# Error while hiding field in Edit form SharePoint Online document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, column

I am getting error message like : Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The node to be inserted is from a different document context."

Can anyone suggest what I am missing here...please fine below code.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
       
    #Config Parameters
    $SiteURL= "SITEURL"
    $ListName="TestBest1"
    $FieldName = "DocumentImportStatus" #Display Name
     
    #Setup Credentials to connect
    $Cred = Get-Credential
    $Cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
     
    Try {
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Cred
       
        #Get the web, List and Field objects
        $Web=$Ctx.Web
        $List=$web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
        $Field = $List.Fields.GetByTitle($FieldName)
     
        #Hide the column from New & Edit forms
        $Field.SetShowInEditForm($False) 
        $Field.SetShowInNewForm($False) 
        $Field.UpdateAndPushChanges($True)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
          
        Write-host -f Green "List Field hidden Successfully!"
    }
    Catch {
        write-host -f Red "Error hiding List Column: " $_.Exception.Message
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a couple of calls to `Load` method... try changing the following part of your script:

```
    $Web=$Ctx.Web
    $List=$web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
    $Field = $List.Fields.GetByTitle($FieldName)
```

to this:

```
$Web=$Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($Web)
$List=$web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$Field = $List.Fields.GetByTitle($FieldName)
$Ctx.Load($Field)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved now find below code for the same.

```
$ColumnName="DocumentImportStatus"
#Get all Site columns from the site
$Fields = $Ctx.web.Fields
$Field = $Fields.GetByTitle($ColumnName)
$Ctx.Load($Field)

#Hide the column from New & Edit forms
$Field.SetShowInEditForm($False)
$Field.SetShowInNewForm($False)
$Field.UpdateAndPushChanges($True)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

Write-host -f Green "Column DocumentImportStatus hidden on Edit form Successfully!"
```